# Let $x$ be an integer with $x \ge 5$. Show that $x + y$ is a perfect square where $y > 0$ and $x > y$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have asked this question before, but didn't really understand the answer given. I found this proof elsewhere.

$Proof:$

$a^2 \le x < (a + 1)^2$  is true for some (unique) positive integer $a$.

We have to show there is some $y > 0$ such that $ y + x = m^2$ is a perfect square for some $m\in\Bbb N$. Since there are no $y > 0$ such that $y + x=$ perfect square for $x = 1, 2, 3, 4$, we claim that the proposal is true for $x \ge 5$.

If $x = 5, 6, 7, 8$, then $a$ is not an integer, so the inequality above won't hold since we know $a$ is a positive integer. So, we'll check these cases  separately.

Suppose $y > 0$.

Then $5 + 4$ is a perfect square. So are $6 + 3$, $7 + 2$ and $8 + 1$.

So it's sufficient to prove our claim for $x > 9 $.

**If $x > 9$, then $a \ge 3$.**

So $a^2 \le x < (a + 1)^2$ holds.

$a^2 -x \le 0 < (a + 1)^2 -x$ follows from $a^2 \le x < (a + 1)^2$.

Since $(a + 1)^2 -x > 0$, we let $y = (a + 1)^2 -x$.

To justify our choice of $y$ and to prove our claim, we also have to show that $x + y$ is a perfect square and that $x > y$:

$x +  y = x + (a + 1)^2 -x = (a + 1)^2$.

$ y = (a + 1)^2 - x$

$ <  (a + 1)^2 - a^2$

$= 2a + 1$

$< a^2$

$\le x$.

---

How can $a = 3$ if $x > 9$? It's obvious that $y$ is derived from $a^2 \le x < (a + 1)^2$, so does that mean that if we prove any statement for $x$ using this particular $y$, then the statement will hold for all $x > 9$? I am just trying to see the relevance of the bolded line in the proof to everything that follows it. At $x = 10$, $a$ is not an integer, so how can we say that our statement is true for all $x > 9$? Very confused here.

Comment: This is ridiculously false. If this were true, then all numbers greater than $x$ would be perfect squares.

Comment: Where can I look up facts about this proposal(theorem)?

Comment: There are none other than it is completely false. Consdider $x=5$ and $y=1$, $5+1=6$ is not a perfect square.

Your first step:

$a^2\le x\ < (a+1)^2$ is **not** true for all positive integers, $a$, let $x=5$ and $a=3$, then $a^2=9>5=x$.

Comment: @AdamHughes If you're here to pick on how he's formulated himself, why don't you propose comcrete improvements? Because it wouldn't take a lot of thinking to figure out what he's really after. Here, I'll go first: When you say "is true for all positive integers $a$", you should really say "is true for _some_ positive integer $a$".

Comment: @Arthur I'm happy to do so, but if the op just has things changed, he may not get what is wrong with what he's doing and so it wouldn't be much of a help to him:  half the battle is being able to communicate the right result.

In particular there are enough errors and strange assumptions, that I cannot divine what he's actually going for. He says $x\ge 5$ is necessary, which it isn't, so it could be there's a vital, missing hypothesis.

Comment: @AdamHughes True, but just blurting out "You've made a mistake. Fix it!" (this is basically what your first comment says) isn't exactly helpful either. The rules of mathematical formulations are intricate and difficult to navigate, so if someone who's not well versed in the language tries to say something, and the first response he gets is along the lines of your first comment, he wouldn't have the skills to nest through his own formulations in order to figure out where you got "All numbers greater than $x$ is a perfect square" from. Also, $x = 4$ or $2$ won't work, since we want $x > y > 0$.

Comment: @Arthur good catch on the $x\ge 5$! And I know it's not always ideal, but it helps some people to be asked these things. I've had some students who respond very well to those sorts of responses (and some who don't). There's no guaranteed formula for student understanding, so I go with case-by-case.

Comment: @AdamHughes, I think I didn't formulate my title correctly. Actually, existence of a single $y$ such that $x + y = m^2$ for some $n \in \mathbb N$ is enough. I shouldve written "prove that $x + y$ is a perfect square for some $y > 0$ and $x > y$.

Comment: If we take into account $a^2 \le x < (a + 1)^2$ is true for some $a$, do we conclude that there's $y$ such that $x + y$ is a perfect square for all $x > 9$ between $a^2$ and $(a + 1)^2$ for some $a$?

Comment: @Erbolat yes, see my answer below for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the current formulation we proceed as follows:

Because $x\ge 5$ we know that $a\ge 2$ so that $(a+1)^2-a^2 = 2a+1\ge 5$, which gives us $(a+1)^2>9$

Then we can let $y=(a+1)^2-x>0$ by assumption. It remains to check $x>y$, but then

$2a+1\ge y$ and $x\ge a^2$, when $a\ge 3$ this means $a^2\ge 2a+1$, so checking the other cases, $x=5,6,7,8$ by hand and noting $x\ge a^2> 2a+1\ge y$ when $a>2$, the result follows.

In particular, we *cannot* claim $a=3$, the key is that $a$ is **at least** 3 when $x\ge 9$, since that makes it so that $a^2>2a+1$ is a strict inequality.